# Find all duplicates in a List and add a number to it

Tags: java

I want to find all duplicates in a list, and change it to the next: 
`{"a", "b", "c", "a", "b"}`

`{"a1", "b1", "c", "a2", "b2"}`

I know how to find a duplicate in a list, but I have difficulty in adding the occurrence number for each identical String.

Comment: Can you change the order of the entries in the list?  If so, the solution is far more simple than existing answers suggest.

Comment: use N buckets (N is number of possible letters), initialized by zeros, each bucket will contain number of occurences. on each symbol, increment a bucket number, and use it to modify corresponding string

Comment: Why is `c` but not `c1` ?

Comment: @mangusta: this can be also string that is size is greater than one.

Comment: @kocko: Because c has no duplicate

Comment: @OrSmith well in this particular question I assume that he is talking about strings with a single char :-) Pshemo provided more generalized solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Map<String, List<Integer>>` which will hold list of indexes each element is placed on. After you create such map just check which element has more then one index, and simply update each of them as you like.

```
String[] arr = { "a", "b", "c", "a", "b" };

Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
        map.get(arr[i]).add(i);
    } else {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(i);
        map.put(arr[i], list);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().size() > 1) {
        int counter = 1;
        for (int i : entry.getValue()) {
            arr[i] += counter++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output: `[a1, b1, c, a2, b2]`

Comment: Though this does not change the value of the String, it only counts duplicates.

Comment: Cool! I just did it myself with an `int[]` to hold the position of the letter in the `String[]`, but your solution is more intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

This is with the JAVA 8 lambdas and streams.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * Created by joshua on 3/17/14.
 */
public class FindDuplicates {


  public static boolean isUnique(String x, List<String> list) {
    return 1 == list.stream().filter(s -> x.equals(s)).count();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> seen = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "a", "b");
    Stream<String> finalStream = list.stream().map(x -> {
      int times = seen.getOrDefault(x, 0) + 1;
      seen.put(x, times);
      return x + times;
    }).map(x -> isUnique(x.substring(0,1), list)? x.substring(0,1) : x);

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(finalStream.toArray()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to change the order of the elements within the array, I would count each element in the array.  If there is only one, do nothing.  If there are more than one, remove all occurrences of that string and re-add it N times adding a counter to the end of each.  Modifying an array while you're iterating through it can be tricky so you may find it easier to create a second array that you push the values into.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to PShemo answer, but little bit different .

```
public class FindDuplicate {
public static final String ONE = "1";
public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] lists = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "b"};

    HashMap<String, PlaceHolder> dupCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        PlaceHolder placeHolder = dupCounts.get(lists[i]);
        if ( placeHolder != null){
            placeHolder.setCount(placeHolder.getCount() +1) ;
            lists[i] = lists[i].concat( placeHolder.toString());
        }else{
            placeHolder = new PlaceHolder();
            placeHolder.setCount(1);
            placeHolder.setFirstPosition(i);
            dupCounts.put(lists[i], placeHolder);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, PlaceHolder> entry: dupCounts.entrySet()){
        if (entry.getValue().getCount() > 1){
            int position = entry.getValue().getFirstPosition();
            lists[position] = lists[position].concat(ONE);
        }
    }

    for (String string : lists) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}


 }

class PlaceHolder{
int count;
int firstPosition;
/**
 * @return the count
 */
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
/**
 * @param count the count to set
 */
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}


/**
 * @return the firstPosition
 */
public int getFirstPosition() {
    return firstPosition;
}
/**
 * @param firstPosition the firstPosition to set
 */
public void setFirstPosition(int firstPosition) {
    this.firstPosition = firstPosition;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return count+"";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more complicated that I first thought.

My first thought was simply to loop over the `List` and use a `Map<String, Integer>` to count the number of occurrences of each character. During the counting you could output the current character concatenated with the running count. The code for this is simple, but the result would be:

```
{"a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "b2"}
```

As we have no way of knowing which characters will be seen again.

So we need to do some pre-processing of the data. First we count the occurrence of each character:

```
final List<String> orig = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "a", "b");
final Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (final String value : orig) {
    final Integer count = counts.get(value);
    if (count == null) {
        counts.put(value, 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(value, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Counts now contains:

```
{b=2, c=1, a=2}
```

New, we cannot simply loop over the original array backwards and decrement the counts here as we see them as we have no way of knowing whether we have a count of 1 because we outputted some values earlier or because this is the only value.

My solution is make a copy of the `count` map and call it `seens`. Here we decrement values as we seem them when we're producing the output.

```
final List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
final Map<String, Integer> seens = new HashMap<>(counts);
for (final String value : orig) {
    final Integer count = counts.get(value);
    if (count == 1) {
        result.add(value);
    } else {
        final Integer seen = seens.get(value);
        result.add(value + (count - seen + 1));
        seens.put(value, seen - 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

So we loop over the original array again and for each item

- If its value in `counts` is `1` then simply output the value
- If its value in `counts` is greater than `1` then get its value from `seens`
- Calculate the number of the item that we're seeing by calculating `count - seen + 1`, i.e. the total number of items minus ( that total minus the number we've seen so far).
- Output `value + number`
- Decrement the number is `seens`